# Can anyone explain this list comprehension?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

```
def unpack_dict(matrix, map_index_to_word):
    table = sorted(map_index_to_word, key=map_index_to_word.get)      
    data = matrix.data
    indices = matrix.indices
    indptr = matrix.indptr        
    num_doc = matrix.shape[0]    
    return [{k:v for k,v in zip([table[word_id] for word_id in 
    indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]] ],
    data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]].tolist())} \
               for i in range(num_doc) ]

wiki['tf_idf'] = unpack_dict(tf_idf, map_index_to_word)
```

[image]

map_index_to_word is dictionary of word:index for few thousand words.
tf_idf is TFIDF sparse vector
DataFrame wiki is displayed in screenshot here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[{k: v for k, v in zip([table[word_id] for word_id in indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i + 1]]],data[indptr[i]:indptr[i + 1]].tolist())} for i in range(num_doc)]
```

is same as :

```
final_list = []
for i in range(num_doc):
    new_list = []
    for word_id in indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i + 1]]:
        new_list.append(table[word_id])

    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in zip(new_list, data[indptr[i]:indptr[i + 1]].tolist()):
        new_dict[k] = v
    final_list.append(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
[{k:v for k,v in zip([table[word_id] for word_id in 
    indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]] ],
    data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]].tolist())} \
               for i in range(num_doc) ]
```

The outer comprehension is

```
[... for i in range(num_doc) ]
```

Just a simple loop `num_doc` times.

Inside that is a dictionary comprehension.

```
{k:v for k,v in zip()}
```

The `zip` takes the `k` key from:

```
[table[word_id] for word_id in indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]] ]
```

and `v` value from:

```
data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]].tolist()
```

So the `i`, outer variable creates the slicing range, `indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]`.

So it's making a list of dictionaries.  The dictionary keys are from `table[word_id]` where `word_id` is found in a range of `indices`, and the value is the corresponding range of `data`.